# Blobstore Python API Download URL using Django HTML template

Tags: python, html, django, html-table, blobstore

I'm creating a dropbox service using BlobStore, however I can't find a good way to implement the file download option from my Django HTML template.

Here is my app.yaml

```
application: my_application
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: /favicon\.ico

- url: (/.*)*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: django
  version: latest
```

Here is the main.py

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.blobstore import BlobInfo
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
import django
import webapp2
import wsgiref.handlers

class UserUpload(db.Model):
    blob_key =      blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(required=True)
    user =          db.UserProperty(required=True)
    user_id =       db.StringProperty(required=True)
    creation =      db.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now_add=True)
    filename =      db.StringProperty()
    content_type =  db.StringProperty()
    size =          db.IntegerProperty()
    MD5 =           db.StringProperty()

# Start Dumpbox login
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @util.login_required
    def get(self):
        logout_url = users.create_logout_url('/')
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        user = users.get_current_user()
        q = UserUpload.all()
        q.filter('user_id =', users.get_current_user().user_id())
        q.order('-creation')
        if user:
            html = template.render('templates/header.html', {'title': 'Dumpbox', 'nickname': user.nickname(), 'url': upload_url})
            html = html + template.render('templates/table.html', { 'file_name': 'File Name',
                                                                    'content_type': 'Content Type',
                                                                    'size': 'Size',
                                                                    'timestamp': 'Creation Date', 
                                                                    'q': q
                                                                    })
            html = html + template.render('templates/footer.html', {'logout_link': logout_url})
            self.response.out.write(html)
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

class LogoutHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.auth.unset_session()
        self.redirect(self.uri_for('home'))

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        user_upload = UserUpload(   user=users.get_current_user(),
                                    user_id=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
                                    blob_key=blob_info.key(),
                                    filename=blob_info.filename,
                                    content_type=blob_info.content_type,
                                    size=blob_info.size,
                                    creation=blob_info.creation,
                                    MD5=blob_info.md5_hash
                                    )
        db.put(user_upload)
        self.redirect('/')

class DownloadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),('/upload', UploadHandler),('/download([^/]+)?', DownloadHandler)],debug=True)
wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Django template uses a table with a checkbox to select file to be downloaded, but I can't find a good way to implement it.

How can tick the checkbox and submit a form to download a blobstore file?

```html
<form method="GET" action="">
    <div id="table-wrapper">
        <div id="table-scroll">
            <table id="file_table" class="display" style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <th style="width:10px"><input type="checkbox"  onclick="checkAll(this)"/></th>
                <th>{{file_name}}</th>
                <th>{{content_type}}</th>       
                <th>{{size}}</th>       
                <th>{{timestamp}}</th>
              </tr>
                {% for file in q %}
                {% if file.size > 0 %}
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="{{file.blob_key}}" type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td><a href="/{{file.blob_key}}/download">{{file.filename}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{file.content_type}}</td>
                    <td>{{file.size}} Bytes</td>
                    <td>{{file.creation}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Download"></p>
</form>
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:
In your template change to line

```
<td><a href="/{{file.blob_key}}/download">{{file.filename}}</a></td>
```

into

```
<td><a href="/download?key={{file.blob_key}}">{{file.filename}}</a></td>
```

In your views add two method:

```
def download(request,client):
    if 'key' in request.GET:
        blob_key_str = request.GET['key']
    if not blob_key_str:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key_str))
    blob = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)

    try:
        return send_blob(blob, save_as=True)
    except ValueError, error:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

and

```
import cgi 
import logging
import urllib
def send_blob(blob_key_or_info, content_type=None, save_as=None):

    CONTENT_DISPOSITION_FORMAT = 'attachment; filename="%s"'
    if isinstance(blob_key_or_info, blobstore.BlobInfo):
      blob_key = blob_key_or_info.key()
      blob_info = blob_key_or_info
    else:
      blob_key = blob_key_or_info
      blob_info = None

    logging.debug(blob_info)
    response = HttpResponse()
    response[blobstore.BLOB_KEY_HEADER] = str(blob_key)

    if content_type:
      if isinstance(content_type, unicode):
        content_type = content_type.encode('utf-8')
        response['Content-Type'] = content_type
      else:
        del response['Content-Type']

    def send_attachment(filename):
      if isinstance(filename, unicode):
        filename = filename.encode('utf-8')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = (CONTENT_DISPOSITION_FORMAT % filename)

    if save_as:
      if isinstance(save_as, basestring):
        send_attachment(save_as)
      elif blob_info and save_as is True:
        send_attachment(blob_info.filename)
      else:
        if not blob_info:
          raise ValueError('The specified file is not found.')
        else:
          raise ValueError(
              'Unexpected value for the name in which file is '
              'expected to be downloaded')

    return response
```

Change this code according to your needs :)